# Would it be faster to plot or to copy reflections in a canvas?

Tags: javascript, optimization, plot, canvas

I'm writing some code that calculates the function

```
c = sin(nπx) × sin(mπy) - sin(mπx) × sin(nπy)
```

to plot [Chladni figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni) on a canvas.  n and m being constants between 0 and 1.

I'm working on optimizing for speed, as even on a 200x200 canvas, it can run a bit clumsily.  One way I've done this is to make use of the fact that it has eight way symmetry around the point (0, 0). That's at the center point of the canvas, so I only have to calculate one corner and reflect it to all eight points.

At this point though, that reflection is taking a significant amount of time.  The way I'm currently doing it is by looping through each point in a right triangle with corners at (0, 0), (w/2, 0) and (w/2, h/2), where w and h are the canvas dimensions.  With each iteration of the loop, the calculated colour is plotted there and in the seven appropriate reflections of it.

The problem is that this plotting seems to be adding a significant amount of time to an already busy algorithm; this is what I'm looking to optimize further.

One way I was thinking of doing so is to plot that single triangle on to another canvas, and copy the entire result to the seven appropriate reflections/rotations.  I don't know though if that would be any faster.

Alternatively, is there a faster way to plot those eight points for each calculated colour?  Currently I just use context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1) for all eight reflections.  but if that could be done more rapidly I'd like to try it.

Below is the current code for the function in question.  If you want to see or test the entire thing, it's a standalone html file that can be found [here](https://github.com/jacobEwing/webtoys/blob/main/chlandi.html), on my GitHub account.

```
        function drawImage() {
            /*
            This function may be hard to follow as I've optimized it to the best of my
            abillity.  The short of it is that each pixel is getting a distinct colour
            based on the function:

            c = sin(n * pi * x) * sin(m * pi * y) - sin(m * pi * x) * sin(n * pi * y)

            In the above function, n and m would have ranges from 0 to one, so instead of
            multiplying them by pi each time, I simply them ranges between zero and pi,
            reducing that to c = sin(n * x) * sin(m * y) - sin(m * x) * sin(n * y);

            a, b, c, and d are those multiples.  a = n * x, b = m * x, etc.  Instead of
            doing the multiplication each time, they're assigned at the start to their
            initial values for the start of the loop, and incremented by the appropriate
            amount, defined as ai, bi, ci, and di.
            */
            var rangeMin = options.parameters.scale * -centerPoint.x / canvasSize;
            var posInc = options.parameters.scale / canvasSize;

            var a = options.parameters.n * rangeMin;
            var ai = options.parameters.n * posInc;

            var c = options.parameters.m * rangeMin;
            var ci = options.parameters.m * posInc;

            var b, bi = options.parameters.n * posInc;
            var bStart = options.parameters.n * rangeMin;

            var d, di = options.parameters.m * posInc;
            var dStart = options.parameters.m * rangeMin;

            var aSine = Math.sin(a);
            var cSine = Math.sin(c);

            for(let x = 0; x < canvas.width >> 1; x++){
                b = bStart;
                d = dStart;
                for(let y = 0; y <= x; y++){

                    let colour = palette[Math.floor(paletteSize * (1 + Math.sin(aSine * Math.sin(d) - cSine * Math.sin(b))) / 2)];
                    context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + colour.red + ', ' + colour.green + ', ' + colour.blue + ')';

                    // it has 8-way symmetry, so we can cut the calculation by a factor of 8:
                    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(canvas.width - x, y, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(x, canvas.height - y, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(canvas.width - x, canvas.height - y, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(y, x, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(canvas.width - y, x, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(y, canvas.height - x, 1, 1);
                    context.fillRect(canvas.width - y, canvas.height - x, 1, 1);

                    b += bi;
                    d += di;

                }
                a += ai;
                c += ci;
                aSine = Math.sin(a);
                cSine = Math.sin(c);
            }
        }
```

Of course, if you spot any other optimizations to be made, don't hesitate to suggest them.  Thanks!

Oh - I should also mention that in the function above, the variables a, b, c, and d are in a weird order.  Not an error, just a poor naming choice that I haven't corrected yet.

Comment: It's possible to test this, use https://jsbench.me

Comment: Use an `ImageData` and manipulate its pixel values directly. That will be magnitudes faster than doing that many 1x1 `fillRect()` calls: https://jsfiddle.net/nekxo9ur/ I get approximately 60FPS on my mid-tier laptop with a 2000x2000px canvas. (Note that I also removed your `toDataURL()` calls to instead show directly the canvas).

Comment: Oh that made a phenomenal difference.  Many thanks.